# Python Emulate strptime behavor

Tags: python, python-3.x, string-parsing

I have a python program that takes file from many sources, all files from the same source have  the same format, but the formats vary greatly.  One source can be in the format **ServerName - ProccessID - Date** another could be **(Date)_Username_ProccessID_Server**.  Currently, to add a new source, with a new format requires a coder to write a parse function for each source.

I've started writing a new adapter, and i'd like to store the file format as a string.   the like first one would be %S - %P - %D, the second could be like (%D)*%U*%P_%S.

What would the best approach for this in python3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this would be reasonable:

```
import re
from collections import namedtuple

Format = namedtuple('Format', 'name format_string regex')
class Parser(object):
    replacements = [Format('server', '%S', r'[A-Za-z0-9]+'),
                    Format('user', '%U', r'[A-Za-z0-9]+'),
                    Format('date', '%D', r'[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}'),
                    Format('process_id', '%P', r'[0-9]+'),
                    ]

    def __init__(self, format):
        self.format = format
        self.re = re.compile(self._create_regex(format))

    def _create_regex(self, format):
        format = re.escape(format)
        for replacement in self.replacements:
            format = format.replace(r'\%s' % replacement.format_string,
                                    r'(?P<%s>%s)' % (replacement.name,
                                                     replacement.regex,
                                                     ),
                                    )
        return format

    def parse(self, data):
        match = self.re.match(data)
        if match:
            return match.groupdict()
        return None
```

Usage:

```
a_parser = Parser("(%D)%U_%P_%S")
print a_parser.parse("(2005-04-12)Jamie_123_Server1")

b_parser = Parser("%S - %P - %D")
print b_parser.parse("Server1 - 123 - 2005-04-12")
```

Output:

```
{'date': '2005-04-12', 'process_id': '123', 'user': 'Jamie', 'server': 'Server1'}
{'date': '2005-04-12', 'process_id': '123', 'server': 'Server1'}
```

Essentially, I'm creating a mapping between the `%?`s in your custom format syntax and a predefined regular expression to match that parameter, then replacing the `%?` strings in the given format string with the corresponding regex to build a parser for that pattern.

This will only work if the characters that delimit a "type" in the format string don't appear in it's regex, or if there's no delimiter, then that the two regex's that are side-by-side don't "interfere" with each other.  For example, with the format string:

```
%U%P
```

And the regexs I've assigned to `user` and `process_id` above, it's impossible tell where `user` ends and `process_id` starts in this string:

```
User1234
```

Is that `User1` and `234` or `User` and `1234`, or any other combination?  But then, even a human can't work that out!